# Convert EXEs written in WISE to WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wise

In our organization we were using WISE installers for creating the MSI and EXEs. Now for implementing the Contineous build process we are moving from WISE to Wix. We were able to convert all the MSIs in Wise to WIX using dark.exe. But we couldn't find a way to create the EXE in WISE to WIX. What is the easy way to create the EXE from WISE to WIX.

Comment: _create the EXE from WISE to WIX_ -- what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: please read it then you will understand

Comment: Depending on the age of the Wise Studio suite he's using, the resulting installer may not be an executable wrapper around an MSI file, but simply a self-extracting executable with some built-in install logic (we have some of these in our legacy code ourselves).  What he's asking is whether there's an automated way to convert a Wise .EXE installer to a WiX MSI package (and AFAIK, there isn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By EXE you most probably mean what's commonly referred to as "bootstrapper" application. The function of that app is to install pre-requisites (third-party programs to required for your program to work), and allow user to set some "global" settings, such as language.

I.e. it just "bootstraps" the installation, i.e. runs something like `msiexec -i <yourmsi>`

Unfortunately there is no "royal path" to port EXE bootstrapper generated by WISE to WIX. Fortunately, it's not usually a big deal to create one from scratch. You can check out WIX bundling docs here:
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/